# How to retain value from a text box on button click from a view, asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have two views

1 . Add.aspx
2. Change.aspx

View Add has a TextBox named menu, where i can type data. I have a 'Add' button below the textbox which redirects to the next view 'Change'
'Change' view has a button named 'Cancel' which on click redirects back to the add page.

My Question is,

How can I persist data entered in the 'Menu' Textbox when I click 'Cancel' from the 'Change' View. Currently it gets cleared. Should I save it in a session ? or is there any other alternative ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing an actual redirect, you can use TempData to store data inbetween views, e.g.:

```
TempData["YourData"] = TextBoxText;
```

See [Passing Data in an ASP.NET MVC Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394711.aspx) on MSDN.